# Handover admin right on google business

Tags: administrative-law

After a rough year building a startup, the CEO decided to ask me, the CTO, to not work anymore, we did not get along at all. I still own shares of the company and we were working with legal on buying me out, but in the meantime, the CEO decided to just kill the company.
I am still the owner of everything related to IT, and he is now asking me to give him admin rights on the google account, which basically will give him the opportunity to kick me out, read my email or misuse my email.

Shall I accept the request ? I am thinking of deleting all my content (mostly my mail, maybe my drive), and sending an official mail stating that I am no longer using my mail, in order to avoid identity theft or so. And yes I do not trust him at all.

Comment: These issues (the Google account and an unilateral intention to dissolve the company) largely depend on your contract and other terms under which the startup was constituted. Typically those clauses specify each partner's rights and obligations. In [this other question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/31117/am-i-at-fault-can-i-get-my-security-deposit-back-from-landlord/), I was able to make an assessment because the OP posted the contract and subsequent records (I just wish the OP didn't remove them from that post, as that gave context).Your country/jurisdiction might also be relevant.

Comment: And by "contract" I mean "at least the relevant parts" of it.